# How to format a TR with two rows, one TD on line two

Tags: html, css

I'd like to format a table with each TR consisting of several TDs on line one and one TD on the second line, taking up the width of the entire row.

Something like this:

```
TD1----TD2----TD3-----
TD4-------------------
```

Not sure where to start with this... CSS? Embedded table? Hoping someone has done something similar.

Comment: Sheesh, couldn't even format the example correctly...

Comment: Well in this case...you don't have a table! Just use grid and define the layout you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a table with multiple  elements in the first row and a single  element in the second row that spans the entire width of the row using HTML and CSS. Here's an example code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      width: 100%;
    }
    td {
      border: 1px solid #000;
      padding: 8px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    td.full-width {
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Column 1</td>
      <td>Column 2</td>
      <td>Column 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="full-width" colspan="3">Full Width</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

In this example, we have a table with two rows (). The first row contains three  elements, and the second row contains one  element with the full-width class, which spans the entire width of the table. The colspan="3" attribute is used to make the second  span all three columns in the first row.

Comment: `td.full-width { width: 100%; }` is not needed ))

Comment: I think we need this because we are looking something like this:
TD1----TD2----TD3-----
TD4-------------------

and the result of my code is like as you're looking for